# How do I get results from interpolation with scikit-learn into a list or dictionary?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a question about returning results from an interpolation. I have the following small DataFrame for which I did a linear regression (polynomial regression).

```
             K  Implied_Volatility_adjusted_settlement
1621531   50.0                                0.479460
1621532   55.0                                0.455387
1621533   60.0                                0.435977
1621534   70.0                                0.403611
1621535   75.0                                0.389726
1621536   80.0                                0.378349
1621537   85.0                                0.368299
1621538   90.0                                0.360906
1621539   95.0                                0.355987
1621540  100.0                                0.354016
1621541  105.0                                0.355128
1621542  110.0                                0.353875
1621543  115.0                                0.355639
1621544  120.0                                0.356574
1621545  130.0                                0.361490
1621546  140.0                                0.370661
1621547  160.0                                0.391378
```

To produce a graph I did the following:

```
# Assign columns to variables
x = df[['K']]
y = df[['Implied_Volatility_adjusted_settlement']]

# Regressions
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)
poly.fit(x_poly, y)
regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(x_poly, y)

# Create plots
plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue')
plt.plot(x, regression.predict(poly.fit_transform(x)), color='red')
plt.title('Polynomial Regression')
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('Implied volatility')
```

Sorry I am not allowed to upload an image (less than 10 reputation), so I will describe the graph: On the x-axis you get value K (60-150) and the y-axis the implied volatility (0.35-0.5). However I want to know the Implied Volatility at point K=65 and K=150 (by using the "formula" of the linear regression).

I am looking for the following: I want to know how I can use the regression to interpolate the implied volatility at K=65 and K=150.

***Solution***
@knh190 provided the following solution:

```py
#Regressions
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)
poly.fit(x_poly, y)
regression = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(x_poly, y)
inter_poly = poly.fit_transform(np.array([65, 150]).reshape((-1, 1))) #new lines of code
inter_result = regression.predict(inter_poly) #new lines of code
print(inter_result)
```

This will get as result the implied volatilities which I am looking for

```py
[[0.41726855]
 [0.38131657]]
```

In the case you are also interested in the graph with the points K=65 and K=160, you can use the following code:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue')  # Data points
plt.plot(x, regression.predict(x_poly), color='red')  # Plot of the expected points
plt.scatter([65, 150], regression.predict(inter_poly), color='purple', marker='x')
plt.title('Polynomial Regression')
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('Implied volatility')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which line is raising the `ValueError`?

Comment: @knh190 I updated question, the ValueError is in essence not really the problem. The main problem is that I don't know I do an interpolation and get the results returned in a list or dict. I already tried some stuff (as uploaded) but most of the times I get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fit_transform` to fit your interpolation positions to desired input shape from `LinearRegression`:

```
xs = poly.fit_transform(np.array([65, 100]).reshape((-1, 1)))
plt.plot([65, 100], regression.predict(xs), color='red')
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I have found a solution. I will update the question, so it can help others!